# Average of a set of numbers

Tags: java, arrays, timer, numbers

In Java, With a timer I have setup, I receive one number every second. What would be a good way of getting an average of all the numbers that comes out of the timer.

I don't want an average of each second, I want a total average, of say, 10 seconds.

Comment: Have a look at codahale metrics.

Comment: Why don't you take the effort to put together a naive algorithm to solve your problem before asking for help? That would also allow you to ask a proper question on a specific programming issue, as per [Stack Overflow guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the following algorithm which only needs two variables (marked bold):

Every time you receive a new element you just

- multiply the current **average** with the **count**
- add the new value to the result (now you have the old sum)
- increment **count** by one (because we now have one more element)
- finally do the sum / count calculation and save the result in the **avg** variable.

This method *avoids iterating over all elements* in your collection which my safe you some time in case of a large number of elements.

```
public class AvgCalculator {
    private double avg = 0.0f;
    private int    cnt = 0;


    /**
     * Calculates a new average based on the current one and
     * a specified new value. After calling this method avg
     * holds the new average value;
     *
     * @return the new average
     */
    public double calcNewAvg(final int newValue) {
        return avg = ((avg * cnt) + newValue) / ++cnt;
    }

    /**
     * Resets the average and count to zero
     */
    public void resetAvg() {
        avg = 0.0f;
        cnt = 0;
    }

    public double getAvg() {
        return avg;
    }
}
```

How to use:

```
final AvgCalculator avgCalc = new AvgCalculator();

avgCalc.calcNewAvg(1);
avgCalc.calcNewAvg(3);
avgCalc.calcNewAvg(1);
avgCalc.calcNewAvg(3);
System.out.println(avgCalc.getAvg);  // should print 2  (1+3+1+3 = 8    8/4 = 2)

avgCalc.resetAvg();
System.out.println(calcNewAvg(5));   // should print 5  (5/1 = 5)
System.out.println(calcNewAvg(15));  // should print 10 (5+15 = 20  20/2 = 10)
```

Output:

```
2.0
5.0
10.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a LinkedList and add the outputed number into the LinkedList when it comes out. Then just use a for loop to get the sum of the LinkedList and divide that by the LinkedList.size()

Comment: This solution might become very unpleasant when used on collections with a large number of elements, because every single element has to be looked at for every new calculation even if it has not changed (and that is clearly the case here).